# RSS viewer web part not working

Tags: 2013, web-part, rss

We have had a site collection set up in SharePoint 2010 where we added quite a few RSS feeds that showed content from other parts of the site collection. When we upgraded the site collection to SharePoint 2013 (with 2010 layout) all the RSS feeds stopped working.

On our 'pure' 2013 test environment, I tried setting up an RSS-viewer that just showed an external RSS feed. No success. It seems as if some kind of feature needs to be enabled in 2013 that wasn't needed in 2010?

On the site collection feeding the RSS, I have checked that RSS is enabled on the site collection level.
On the site collection receiving the RSS, I have checked that RSS is enabled on the site collection level.
SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection feature is enabled
Lists that feed have RSS enabled

The error we get on the 2013 in 2010 layout site collection is:
- The RSS Web Part does not support approved RSS sources (roughly translated from the Danish error message)

The error we get on the 'pure' 2013 site collection is:
- An unexpected error occured when processing your request. See logs for further information and correct the error (roughly translated from the Danish error message)

Anyone know what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when the RSS viewer web part carries out a `http request` to retrieve a `XML content` from a RSS Feed data source, it does not include a `User-Agent` property in the header of the HTTP Request.

However, in our case, due to security rules, an equipment `(firewall or proxy?)` in the company providing the RSS feed didn't allow missing `User-Agent` properties and an empty XML stream was returned to the `SharePoint RSS viewer`. This is why I had this error message in SP the log `XML root is missing`.

To conclude, the Warc company has kindly updated its security rules. so that,  its RSS feed returns a `proper XML content` even if it is requested with a missing `User-Agent` Property and this fixed my problem.

By the way, I think my problem was also due to the fact that our SharePoint server is not connected to the `web through a proxy server`. Indeed in this case, the proxy server would have added a `user-agent property` avoiding this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the content query application? If you only want to collect RSS feeds within your site collection this is the only tool of which I know will do the job. Unless you have Kerberos set up.

Comment: Hi. It's not much of a problem anymore as we've used other solutions. Was just wondering why it worked in 2010 but not in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Error appeared to lie with the firewall, preventing til Web Frontend Server from initialising traffic to both RSS feeds outside the house and to other SharePoint applications.